# RestAssured+Java. How to exclude a specific field from request logs?

Tags: java, rest-assured

Im using a RestAssured filter to get request and response logs. The following method doing that:

```
public RequestSpecification setUpRequestSpec() {
        return given()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("PTToken", ProjectData.practiTestConfigs.ptToken())
                .filters(new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter());
}
```

When requests are sending all the Request and Response logs are shown, but the problem is that in request body there is a field in which Im sending a picture in Base64 format, and it looks like a thousands of characters. How can I exclude this field with Base64 picture only from Request logs?

As far as I understood I have to write a custom filter for that purpose... maybe someone can give an example.

Request log sample:

```
{
"data": {
    "type": "instance",
    "attributes": {
        "run-duration": "00:00:01",
        "exit-code": "1",
        "instance-id": "88344198",
        "automated-execution-output": "Step"
    },
    "files": {
        "data": [
            {
                "filename": "attachment",
                "content_encoded": "  ......a lot of chars. this field I'd like to exclude from logs .... "
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**: Use `RequestLoggingFilter` to log specific which part in request. [Detail](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/latest/io/restassured/filter/log/RequestLoggingFilter.html#with-io.restassured.filter.log.LogDetail...-)

```java
import static io.restassured.filter.log.LogDetail.*;

...

.filters(
   RequestLoggingFilter.with(URI, METHOD, HEADERS, PARAMS), 
   new ResponseLoggingFilter()
);
```

**Solution 2**: Write custom RequestLoggingFilter

```java
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.filter.Filter;
import io.restassured.filter.FilterContext;
import io.restassured.internal.support.Prettifier;
import io.restassured.parsing.Parser;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.FilterableRequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.specification.FilterableResponseSpecification;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class CustomRequestLoggingFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String HIDDEN = "****";
    private static final String TAB = "\t";
    private final PrintStream stream;
    private String path;

    public CustomRequestLoggingFilter(PrintStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public CustomRequestLoggingFilter() {
        this.stream = System.out;
    }

    public CustomRequestLoggingFilter(String path) {
        this.stream = System.out;
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec, FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
        String body = requestSpec.getBody().toString();
        if (this.path != null) {
            body = JsonPath.parse(body).set(path, HIDDEN).jsonString();
            String prettified = new Prettifier().prettify(body, Parser.JSON);
            body = StringUtils.replace(prettified, SystemUtils.LINE_SEPARATOR, SystemUtils.LINE_SEPARATOR + TAB + TAB + TAB + TAB);
        }
        stream.println(body);
        return ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
    }
}
```

To use it in client code, need to specific path to key you want to exclude. I don't like excluding key-value in body --> mis information in log, so I change to hidden character `***`.

```
.filters(
  new CustomRequestLoggingFilter("$.data.files.data[0].content_encoded"), 
  new ResponseLoggingFilter()
);
```

Sample log:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "type": "instance",
        "attributes": {
            "run-duration": "00:00:01",
            "exit-code": "1",
            "instance-id": "88344198",
            "automated-execution-output": "Step"
        },
        "files": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "filename": "attachment",
                    "content_encoded": "****"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In 1st case - as I've understood I can do something like: RequestLoggingFilter.with(BODY) - but how to exclude a specific field from the body and not show it in logs?

Comment: In 2nd case of using CustomRequestLoggingFilter, how does the logic of exclusion specific field look? How it should be implemented?

Comment: @SerhiiBozhyk. 1st case, no, you cannot exclude one specific field in body. You can only cho which part will be logged, such as HEADER, URI. In 2nd case, you can require the request information of requestSpec and log what you need. In the example, I only log the URI. Could you add a log of your sample request, I want to see how it look like.

Comment: So, the 1st case is not relevant to my question. For 2nd one, I have added the request log example. Thanks!

Comment: @SerhiiBozhyk I updated the code. If it solves your problem, pls mark it the correct answer and upvote if you can.

Comment: Looks working, Thanks.